# Can't pass data from model into Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-partialview

The Issue is I can't pass data from model to PartialView. Here is how I've done it.

My PartialsController.cs

```
public PartialViewResult _GridView()
    {

        var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var ranks = ApplicationDbContext.Ranks.ToList();

        foreach (var item in ranks)
        {
            if (currentUser.ReputationPoints > item.ReputationPoints && currentUser.ReputationPoints < item.PointsToAdvance)
            {
                currentUser.UserRankId = item.Id;
                ApplicationDbContext.Entry(currentUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        var Rank = ApplicationDbContext.Ranks.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == currentUser.UserRankId);



        return PartialView(currentUser);
    }
```

And my Partial View called _GridView.cshtml

```
@model Destiny.Models.ApplicationUser
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Zalogowano jako " + Model.CurrentUser.Gamertag, "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Wyloguj</a></li>
    </ul>
}
  }
  else
          {
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Zarejestruj", "Register", "Account",routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Zaloguj", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
 }
```

The partialView demands another ViewModel (Which is used for my Home/Index by the way), and the thing is the fact I am 100% sure that I've done something wrong with passing data, but I don't know what is it. It's my 1st time messing with partial Views.

Comment: What error you are seeing? How are you rendering the partial view? Did you debug the code/

Comment: The error said that the data passed in the controller is PostList (My view Model) but view demands ApplicationUser. Partial view was rendered this way                                                                                                                 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/_GridView.cshtml")                                            And it is in _Layout.cshtml which i have passed no model in whatshowever

Comment: what is the type of currentUser object??

Comment: It is an ApplicationUser

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/5ZjRe It says that Model passed to dictionary is type of Destiny.Models.PostList, meanwhile dictionary demands model Destiny.Models.ApplicationUser. As you can see though, I've passed ApplicationUser to the controller. I suspect that controller doesn't work with this partial at all.

Comment: And you are seeing this error when you are browsing home page? Image quality is really bad. Can't make anything out of it. Can you upload some good quality capture?

Comment: Yes, because _Layout.cshtml which this partial is bound to is rendered at the Index of homepage.

Comment: use @Html.RenderAction instead of @Html.Partial( in the layout

Comment: this way **@{Html.RenderAction("_GridView");}**

Comment: Compilation error, Can't unexplicitly convert "void" to "object".

Comment: this way **@{Html.RenderAction("_GridView");} ** 

???

Comment: It works, forgot to add brackets on the beginning

Comment: Okay, I guess I got it. It worked perfectly fine. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
   @Html.RenderAction
```

instead of

```
   @Html.Partial( in the layout –
```

This Way

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("_GridView");}
```